# Why do only some of my replace method calls work when adding values to an email template?

Tags: javascript, email, google-apps-script, replace

I have code written in App Script that uses a Google Doc as a template for an email and then sends then email. In the template, there are lots of parameters that I need to replace with variables using the replace() method. Here is the link with edit access to the email template with some information redacted: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1cq8SGVLwfNFAqxDd-LkRDlHCSqyYKuuqYnxO6nfV39k/edit?usp=sharing

Html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <?!= include('script'); ?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="sendEmailBtn">Send Email</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Code from Code.js:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate();
}
function include(filename) {
  return 
HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}

function sendEmail(data) {
  let body = createEmailBody(data);
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "*****Your Email*****",
    subject: "Test Email",
    htmlBody: body,
  });
  Logger.log("Email length: " + body.length);
}

function createEmailBody(data) {
 const templateId = 

DocumentApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/document/d/1cq8SGVLwfN 
          FAqxDd-LkRDlHCSqyYKuuqYnxO6nfV39k/edit').getId();
          let body = docToHtml(templateId); //Convert the template to html
      Logger.log("Document length: " + body.length)

  body = body.replace(/{Total Score}/g, data['Total Score']);
  body = body.replace(/{Overall Totals}/g, data['Overall Totals']);
  body = body.replace(/{Overall Description}/g, data['Overall Description']);
  body = body.replace(/{Name}/g, data['Name']);
  body = body.replace(/{Organization}/g, data['Organization']);
  body = body.replace(/{question1}/g, data['Question 1']);
  body = body.replace(/{question2}/g, data['Question 2']);
  body = body.replace(/{question3}/g, data['Question 3']);
  body = body.replace(/{question4}/g, data['Question 4']);
  body = body.replace(/{question5}/g, data['Question 5']);
  body = body.replace(/{question6}/g, data['Question 6']);
  body = body.replace(/{question7}/g, data['Question 7']);
  body = body.replace(/{question8}/g, data['Question 8']);
  body = body.replace(/{question9}/g, data['Question 9']);
  body = body.replace(/{question10}/g, data['Question 10']);
  body = body.replace(/{question11}/g, data['Question 11']);
  body = body.replace(/{question12}/g, data['Question 12']);
  body = body.replace(/{question13}/g, data['Question 13']);
  body = body.replace(/{question14}/g, data['Question 14']);
  body = body.replace(/{question15}/g, data['Question 15']);
  body = body.replace(/{question16}/g, data['Question 16']);
  body = body.replace(/{question17}/g, data['Question 17']);
  body = body.replace(/{question18}/g, data['Question 18']);
  body = body.replace(/{question19}/g, data['Question 19']);
  body = body.replace(/{question20}/g, data['Question 20']);
  body = body.replace(/{question21}/g, data['Question 21']);
  body = body.replace(/{question22}/g, data['Question 22']);
  body = body.replace(/{question23}/g, data['Question 23']);
  body = body.replace(/{question24}/g, data['Question 24']);

  return body;
}

function docToHtml(docId) {
// Downloads a Google Doc as an HTML string.
let url = 'https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=' +
        docId + '&exportFormat=html';
    var param = {
    method: 'get',
    headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
  };
      let doc = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, param).getContentText();
      Logger.log("Doc length: " + doc.length);
      return doc;
    }
```

Code from JS file:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    let btn = document.getElementById('sendEmailBtn');
    btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
      console.log("clicked");
      let emailParams = {
        'Total Score': '-Test total score-',
        'Overall Totals': '-Test overall totals-',
        'Overall Description': '-Test overall description-',
        'Name': '-Test name-',
        'Organization': '-Test organization-'
      };
      for(let i = 1; i <= 24; i++) {
        emailParams['Question '+i] = '-Test question' + i + '-';
      }
      google.script.run.sendEmail(emailParams);
    });
  })
</script>
```

My problem lies with the replace() methods. The email that is sent to me has the values successfully replaced only up to 'question6'

Why do they stop being replaced? I thought it might be a size issue, but am unsure about that after I logged the size of the document (which was 24100) and the size of the email (which was 24297). Also, the email sends all of the template doc, only not all the values are replaced. I also made sure that the replace() methods referenced the exact text from the template.

Comment: Not an answer to your problem, but if you align the field names in `emailParams` and the Google doc template you can reduce all these replaces with a single one: `body = body.replace(/\{([^\}]+)\}/g, (m, c1) => data[c1]);`

Comment: Could you post a minimal reproducible example? That is, sample email template, e.g. provide a hard-coded `body` instead of `let body = docToHtml(templateId)`

Comment: Yes. I just updated the original post. Hopefully that's what you were looking for

Comment: Also, I just changed the replace from /{question7}/g to /question7/g  (just removed the brackets) and it worked. Any idea why the brackets would cause the problem?

Comment: No, I was looking for the `body` template, as in `let body = "blah {Total Score} blah..."`

Comment: Without seeing your orginal body tempalte with `{question7}` I can't say why it does not work

Comment: Sorry I don't think I understand. The google doc I shared is the template. It's loaded into the code.js file and saved in the "body" variable. That google doc is the template with the "blah {Total Score} blah..." in it. So the body variable contains an html version of the google doc, retaining styling. I'm not sure what it would look like to actually hard code the google doc into JavaScript. I could give you the return value of docToHtml() if that's what you want.

Comment: Yea, I get that. But to debug we need all the data for a minimal reproducible example, hence my suggestion to copy the template text in here. (The issue is unlikely with reading the template doc)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I just updated the post to hopefully include the minimal reproducible example using Apps Script. Just make sure to add your email to the sendEmail() function. It still uses the link to the google doc, but you should have access to it. Let me know if you don't have access to the document. Thanks

Comment: Let me try one last time to get a minimal reproducible example: The loading of the template doc and sending of the email is irrelevant for the problem you have, so take it out. In return provide the HTML text of the template. That is instead of `let body = docToHtml(templateId)` provide 'let body = "Foo {Total Score}, bar {Overall Totals}, etc"'.

Comment: Real quick before I put the raw html of the document. There is a lot of styling included in the document. Just want to make sure you want the whole entirety of the html and css of the document to get the closest to what the program is actually using. Do you want me to download the template document as html and use that for the body variable?

Comment: You can shorten the HTML version, but keep all `{...}` in there.

Comment: Peter, thanks for your help. I found a fix for my problem. For whatever reason, when I erase the bracket variables and manually type them in, it is then successfully replaced. Before I post an answer to this, would you know if that was maybe a formatting issue?

Comment: I suspected a formatti9ng issue, that's why very early on I asked for a minimal reproducible example

Answer (score 1):

If you suspect a memory quota issue you can change all your replaces to a chain:

```
  body = body.replace(/{Total Score}/g, data['Total Score'])
    .replace(/{Overall Totals}/g, data['Overall Totals'])
    .replace(/{Overall Description}/g, data['Overall Description'])
    .replace(/{Name}/g, data['Name'])
    .replace(/{Organization}/g, data['Organization'])
    .replace(/{question1}/g, data['Question 1'])
    .replace(/{question2}/g, data['Question 2'])
    // etc
```

Also, if you align the field names in `emailParams` and your Google doc template you can reduce all these replaces with a single one:

```
  body = body.replace(/\{([^\}]+)\}/g, (m, c1) => data[c1]);
```

Further, your `emailsParams` object can be simplified:

```
let emailParams = {
  'Total Score': getTotalScore(),
  'Overall Totals': getOverallTotalsWord(),
  'Overall Description': getOverallDescription(),
  'Name': name,
  'Organization': organization
};
for(let i = 1; i <= 24; i++) {
  emailParams['Question '+i] = getSelectedOption('question'+i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for those suggestions Peter. I tried chaining the replaces, but nothing changed. It also might be helpful to note that there is another {Total Score} near the bottom of the template after all of the {question(x)} parameters that is being successfully replaced

Comment: Could you post a minimal reproducible example? That is, sample email template, e.g. provide a hard-coded `body` instead of `let body = docToHtml(templateId)`